# python not able to import

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, import

Importing inside the function, Python is not able to import this. Outside the function, it works fine. This is actually a Django server and view_page function gets called from outside the file.

So, basically doing this throws up an error "`Error : No module named plotting`"

My code:

```
def view_page():
   from bokeh.plotting import figure # This throws up an error

   pass
```

This works absolutely fine;

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure

def view_page():
    pass
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: This can be a case of circular import, make sure you haven't imported the same module from the file you're importing the view.

Comment: Error : No module named plotting

Comment: v1k45 : No it cannot be the case of circular import. I am importing this library for the first time here

Comment: Is the indentation the same as you've shown here?

Comment: If the import outside the function works, why do you want to do the import inside it instead?

Comment: Actually I don't directly have an import inside the function, I do an exec inside the function which has the following code and hence the import

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend using exec inside a web application, but that's a different matter...  Have you tried printing `sys.path` in your code that is being run by the exec function?